# Javascript adding sort parameter to URL after submitting a search

Tags: javascript

I would like it to automatically sort from low to high once I click the search button on cvs.com website. Below is what I have so far. The issue with this is that it keeps refreshing the page.

How do I stop the page from constantly refreshing after the sort parameter has been set?

```
if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    searchParams.set("sort", "pa");
    window.location.search = searchParams.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.stop();`

```js
if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    searchParams.set("sort", "pa");
    window.location.search = searchParams.toString();
    window.stop();
}
```

Try this code as it will not refresh the browser:

```js
if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
      const url = new URL(window.location);
      url.searchParams.set('sort', 'pa');
      window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
}
```

For more details refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop)

Comment: I tried window.stop(); but the sort parameter was not added to the url after I used the searched bar on the website. With my original code, it looks like it kind of works after the browser refreshes twice. Is there a way to make it reload only 2 times after I search?

Comment: @MattLevis Try new code which I have added in the reply.